# Makefile include file for same targets

Tags: makefile, multiple-makefiles

I have a large project using recursive Make.  Almost all the Makefiles are the same though.  I'm basically building all the object files into the same directory like this:

```
$(OBJ)/%.o: %.c
        $(COMPILE) ${INCLUDES} -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ)/%.o: %.cpp
        ${CXX} ${INCLUDES} ${FLAGS}  -c -fPIC $< -o $@
```

Is it possible to put these targets in an include file so I don't have to put the same lines in every Makefile?

include I've only used for shared variables and when I tested this using include it did not work.

Comment: It should work with `include`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: oops you're right...it did work.  Turns out some of the Makefiles were different slightly  Thanks!